# Need to change the wording of an error message

Tags: magento-1.9, messages

i need to change the wording of a error message which is displayed in the edit information page in accounts [image] but i dont really know what file to find this error message in. I tried changing the message in validation.js but it didn't apply it to this page.

If you know what file I have to change in order to change the error message please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your theme folder create a `locale/[locale_code]/translate.csv` file.

Example: `app/design/frontend/[package]/[theme]/locale/en_US/translate.csv`

And add this line:

```
"Please make sure your passwords match.","Translated String."
```

And finally refresh `Translations` cache.

Comment: Wouldnt that translate all places where it says "Please make sure your passwords match". For example fi they make a new password and the confirmed password doesn't match it will say the new phrase? as i need to just change it on this page

Comment: Message in your screenshot is generated by PHP. If you want to change original message look in `validate` method of `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer` class.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried amending the error messages using the transalation.csv file? There you should be able to amend the message to read whatever you want so long as the string matches that in the code.